# How to set, Laravel Queue Payload format

Tags: laravel, queue

How to set, Laravel Queue Payload format.

I don't want to change the source code.

source code: 
File Path: vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Queue.php

```
 /**
 * Create a payload for an object-based queue handler.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $job
 * @return array
 */
protected function createObjectPayload($job)
{
    return [
        'displayName' => $this->getDisplayName($job),
        'job' => 'Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler@call',
        'maxTries' => $job->tries ?? null,
        'timeout' => $job->timeout ?? null,
        'timeoutAt' => $this->getJobExpiration($job),
        'data' => [
            'commandName' => get_class($job),
            'command' => serialize(clone $job),
        ],
    ];
}
```

Queue data:

```
{
"displayName": "App\\Jobs\\SendReminderEmail",
"job": "Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call",
"maxTries": null,
"timeout": null,
"timeoutAt": null,
"data": {
    "commandName": "App\\Jobs\\SendReminderEmail",
    "command": "O:26:\"App\\Jobs\\SendReminderEmail\":8:{s:11:\"0000*0000username\";s:19:\"2017-12-29 07:05:53\";s:6:\"0000*0000job\";N;s:10:\"connection\";N;s:5:\"queue\";N;s:15:\"chainConnection\";N;s:10:\"chainQueue\";N;s:5:\"delay\";N;s:7:\"chained\";a:0:{}}"
}
}
```

But,i want this format:

```
{
"message": {
    "Username": "test",
},
"messageType": [
    "urn:message:App\\Jobs\\SendReminderEmail"
]
}
```

Comment: is there a special reason for it? laravel needs those data in the payload to perform the jobs. if you really need more data, I recommend you add it to the current one, instead of replacing it.